# Copying data from a sharepoint connection to a local repeating table

Tags: c#, sharepoint, infopath

I'm looking to copy data from a sharepoint connection to a local repeating table so that I can modify and re-submit the data.

I've been looking the article below which seems to describe what I require:
http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/copy-rows-from-sharepoint-list-to-main-data-source.htm

I'm not familiar with C# so I would like some help on the code as the upper table should match the lower table in the the preview

Thanks in advance

[Infopath form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soRKP.png)

[Secondary connection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVcwg.png)

[Preview of form after clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6E3Q.png)

C# code linked to button
    private void AddItem(string title, string id)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode group = doc.CreateElement("group2",
            NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));

```
        XmlNode field = doc.CreateElement("field1",
        NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
        XmlNode node = group.AppendChild(field);
        node.InnerText = title;

        field = doc.CreateElement("field2",
        NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
        node = group.AppendChild(field);
        node.InnerText = id;

        doc.AppendChild(group);

        MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode(
        "/my:myFields/my:group1",
        NamespaceManager).AppendChild(doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator());
    }

    private void DeleteFirstEmptyItem()
    {
        XPathNavigator domNav = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNavigator itemNav = domNav.SelectSingleNode(
        "/my:myFields/my:group1/my:group2[1]",
        NamespaceManager);

        if (itemNav != null)
            itemNav.DeleteSelf();
    } 

    public void CTRL13_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        XPathNavigator secDSNav = DataSources["TestCustomList"].CreateNavigator();

        // Retrieve the rows of the secondary data source
        XPathNodeIterator rows = secDSNav.Select(
        "/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW",
        NamespaceManager);

        // Loop through the rows of the secondary data source and fill the repeating table
        while (rows.MoveNext())
        {
            string title = rows.Current.SelectSingleNode(
            "/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Title", NamespaceManager).Value;
            string id = rows.Current.SelectSingleNode(
            "/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:ID", NamespaceManager).Value;

            // Add the item to the repeating table
            AddItem(title, id );
        }

        // Remove the first empty item from the repeating table
        DeleteFirstEmptyItem();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, it looks like the declaration of string variables title and id shouldn't refer to the full Xpath

```
while (rows.MoveNext())
{
    string title = rows.Current.SelectSingleNode(
    "d:Title", NamespaceManager).Value;
    string id = rows.Current.SelectSingleNode(
    "d:ID", NamespaceManager).Value;

     // Add the item to the repeating table
     AddItem(title, id);
}
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltOVl.png)